# How can I connect to a remote IIS server?

Tags: iis, remote-access, iis-8, iis-manager

I have 2 servers which are located in different networks. On each of them IIS is installed. When I try to connect to the first IIS server from the second, it gives me error: "Could not connect to the specified computer. The remote name could not be resolved". Fierwall is switched off. Maybe I should configure something in DNS or somwhere else?

**Update:**
Ping is ok, no packages are lost.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you "ping" the address from the command prompt?

If it comes up with host not found, then you either need to configure DNS on the server trying to get to the remote computer OR create a static hosts file entry pointing the name to the ip address...